# Makefile recipe failed

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to write a makefile for a program, which is written in c++ and uses routines written in fortran. I've written my makefile like this:

```
#
OBJ = main.o graph.o
LAPACK= lapack/dstevx.o lapack/lsame.o lapack/xerbla.o lapack/dlamch.o lapack/disnan.o \
        lapack/dlae2.o lapack/dlaebz.o lapack/dlaev2.o lapack/dlagtf.o lapack/dlagts.o
BLAS = blas/dscal.o blas/dswap.o blas/dcopy.o
DEPS = graph.h
#
FC      =  c:/MinGW/bin/gfortran
FCFLAGS =  -c -O2
LD      =  c:/MinGW/bin/gfortran 
FC      =  gfortran
GC      =  g++.exe 
LD      =  gfortran 
CFLAGS  =  -I.
CXXFLAGS=  -g -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wno-write-string
#
# clear list of default suffixes, and declare default suffixes
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .f .f90 .c .o .cpp .h
# default rule to make .o files from .f files
.f.o  : ;       $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) $*.f -o $*.o
.f90.o  : ;       $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) $*.f90 -o $*.o
.c.o  : ;       $(GC) $(CXXFLAGS) $*.c -c $*.o
.cpp.o  : ;       $(GC) $(CXXCFLAGS) $*.cpp -c $*.o
#
graph.exe: ${OBJ} $(BLAS) $(LAPACK)
    $(GC) $(CXXCFLAGS) $(BLAS) $(LAPACK) ${OBJ}  -o graph.exe
#
clean :
    rm.exe -f  *.mod ${BLAS} ${LAPACK} ${OBJ} ${LIB} *.exe core
```

However, when I'm trying to use it, I'm getting `recipe for graph.o failed` error. Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: You should always cut and paste the complete, exact error message you get along with the last few lines of output before it, at least.  With nothing more than "recipe failed" there's nothing we can suggest to help.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I can see is that the way this command is written

```
$(GC) $(CXXFLAGS) $*.c -c $*.o
```

it will attempt to compile the file `graph.o`